# Как настроить переадресацию в wordpress в файле .htaccess

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть сайт который находится по адресу http://172.16.98.25/localhost/
я настроил проксирование в apache на домен [http://мойсайт.онлайн/](http://xn--80arbjktj.xn--80asehdb/)

---

По итогу на сайт по ссылке [http://мойсайт.онлайн/](http://xn--80arbjktj.xn--80asehdb/)  заходит без проблем и информация отображается корректно, но ссылки все движка wordpress введут по адресу http://172.16.98.25/localhost/ . Возможно ли настроить так, что бы все ссылалось на [http://мойсайт.онлайн/..](http://xn--80arbjktj.xn--80asehdb/..). через файл .htaccess

---

Apache конфиг

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmasters@mail.ru

    ServerName xn--80arbjktj.xn--80asehdb

    ServerAlias www.xn--80arbjktj.xn--80asehdb xn--80arbjktj.xn--80asehdb

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://172.16.98.25/localhost/

    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.16.98.25/localhost/

    ErrorLog logs/vonline-error.log

    CustomLog logs/vonline-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно формировать в wp-config.php адрес сайта в зависимости от хоста

Например, так (вставить в wp-config.php):

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) && ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) )
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        
$url_protocol = 'http://';       
        
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
            $url_protocol = 'https://';
        }

        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
            $url_protocol = 'https://';
        }
} elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        $url_protocol = 'https://';
}        
         
$url = $url_protocol .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

define('WP_HOME',$url);

define('WP_SITEURL',$url);
```

Comment: НИЧЕГО НЕ НАЙДЕНО
Запрошенную информацию найти не удалось. Возможно, будет полезен поиск по сайту.

Comment: После этого изменения нельзя зайти на любую другую страницу сайта

Comment: @Tand сложно что-то сказать - не видя сайта. код в ответе изменяет только настройки адреса сайта. он не изменяет главный запрос на wordpress. попробуйте поставить плагин query monitor. в нем видно запросы , которые создает wordpress

Comment: Query monitor не работает в данном случае

Comment: /#page-content:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):210 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
/#page-content:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Tand нужно смотреть в логах веб-сервера. неправильно сделаны настройки на apache

Comment: а какие нужно выставить ?